# How can I create sub-sheets in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I have a workbook in excel that displays information from multiple processes and each of these processes has multiple sub-processes.

I can display information for each process easily using one sheet per process, but I would really like a way to create sub-sheets to show sub-process information.

***Does excel support this functionality?***

---

**Ex:**

[image]

```
              ^
              |
              +---- How can I make "Subprocess1, 2, etc..." tabs
                    beneath the "Process1" tab?
```

---

***If Excel does not support this functionality, is there a workaround that can simulate sub-sheets to better present this kind of data?***

Comment: Excel itself may not be the right tool for you for this.. You could investigate the VBA side and use forms to create subforms potentially..

Comment: I need to present the data in Excel for a product test for a work assignment.  It is required that all product tests be done in Excel.  For now I'm just grouping tabs by coloring them, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Well think about taking a step further back and using separate workbooks that have links in a master workbook.. Each workbook would be a process and then inside each of those, each tab can be a subprocess, with the master workbook collecting them all so from the user's standpoint they all appear to be from one.